# vertical scrollbar is not working in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, listbox

I have a listbox under stackpanel and vertical scrollbar is visible but the scroller is not coming. The horizontal works fine. I can scroll across the listbox but not vertically.

```
<ListBox Width="700"  Height="205"  x:Name="log_Enteries"  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
        </ListBox>
```

I know setting height and width is not wise but it was desperate try I guess.

Comment: Actually I replaced listbox with the textbox and added scrollviewer properties which worked for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's in a `StackPanel`. A vertically-oriented `StackPanel` will give its children whatever height they ask for, even if it means they run off the screen. Hence, the vertical `ScrollBar` will never show. Choose the right panel and you'll see the `ScrollBar`.

Comment: I cannot think of any other panel than stack panel becuase it fits my needs. It consist of a grid follows by a listbox.When you click an item from grid it will show details in listbox.

Comment: You could just use a `Grid` instead with the appropriate proportions for each row.

Comment: I tried putting them under grid but it doesn't work. <Grid><ListBox></Grid>

Comment: @alice7 Setting a fixed Height for the ScrollBar enables the vertical scroll bar if the content exceeds that Height

Answer (score 1):

Use `MaxHeight` of your `ListBox` instead
You can also set your `MaxHeight` to parent `StackPanel` to achive want you want somthing like this:

```
MaxHeight="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type StackPanel}}, Path=Height}"
```